# Laravel - how to repopulate input list data after validation

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to repopulate an input list data after validation. I tried the same way as input but it doesn't work. The element looks like this and I would like to use the previous input if the validation has failed:
[Phone list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Zin.png)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>Phones: 
        <a id="add-phone-input">
          <i class="fas fa-plus btn-success btn float-right mb-5">
          </I>
        </a>
     </label>
     <ol id="phones-ul" class="row p-0 m-0" style="list-style: none;">
         <li class="organization-phones-li mb-2 col-md-4">
              <input class="form-control selectpicker organization_phones"  type="text" name="organization_phones[]" value="{{ old('organization_phones[]') }}">
         </li>
     </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

```
 <div class="col-md-12{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Phones: 
        <a id="add-phone-input">
          <i class="fas fa-plus btn-success btn float-right mb-5">
          </I>
        </a>
     </label>
     <div>
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" >
        @if ($errors->has('name'))
           <span class="help-block">
           <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
           </span>
        @endif
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateInput($request);
   .....
}
    private function validateInput($request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'min:10'
    ]);
}
```

Hope this gives u some idea.